# How to hit url in using POST request in php

Tags: php, web

How to hit a url with the Content-Type header set to application/json.

My code returns "request not successfull" (the else side of the condition). I'm a beginner so please help me understand why this is not working.

Code:

```
$data_string=json data here;    
    $ch = curl_init('www.here is url');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));                                                                                                                                  
    if(curl_exec($ch))
        echo "request successfull";
    else
        echo "request not successfull"

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Why are you sending that httpheader? Using `json_decode( $data_string, true)` should do the job perfectly, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes the jason was fine actually the problem was in the site that i was hitting..they have SSL cert that was expired. now everthing is fine and working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Is all you need. Custom request is for the lesser-used HTTP verbs. To find out why the curl request failed, use

```
echo curl_error($ch);
```

Comment: by curl_error($ch);
i'm getting this error SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: Either your curl install doesn't have a list of CAs to validate against, or the site you're hitting has an invalid cert.

Comment: If so can you open that page in browser without getting a warning?

Comment: Thanks all.. i got it.. acctually i was hitting a website that have certificate to verify first.. now its working..

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

cURL is setup to not trust any CAs, thus it won’t trust any web server’s certificate.

Try this to accept any SSL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

The proper fix on this link

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Hope this helps